# Project Euler #7 Java code not working

Tags: java, primes

I've been working on Project Euler #7, and can't figure out why my program is not working.  The problem is as follows:

By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.

What is the 10 001st prime number?

This is my program so far:

```
public class Euler7 {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    long count = 1;
    long primes = 0;
    while (primes <= 10001) {
        if (isPrime(count)){
            primes++;
            if (primes == 10001) {
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }

    count++;
    }
}
public static boolean isPrime (long i) {
    if (i <= 1) return false;
    else if (i == 2 || i == 3) return true;
    else if (i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0) return false;
    else {
    for (int n = 3; n < Math.sqrt(i); n+=2) {
        if (i % n == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

}

EDIT:  To be clear, it returns the value 104033, but WolframAlpha says the 10001st prime is 104743

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code incorrectly believes that some full squares of primes are prime as well. In particular, your `isPrime(25)` returns `true`.

This should be enough to figure out a fix (ok, one more hint: all you need is adding a single character).

Comment: I think I got it, I need to have n <= Math.sqrt(i), because it doesnt go up to the root